# ionic 3 angular passing multiple sets of data to popover

Tags: angular, ionic3, popover

I have a ionic 3 angular app. And i am using popover to show some data.

I invoke it using:

```
 popover = this.editOptyPopup.create(EditOptyPage, rw, { cssClass: 'edit-opty-popover'});
```

here rw is one JSON structure. I got another logical json object and i want to pass that too. What would be the recommended way here?

One way I think is creating a wrapper json containing both the objects. however, sort of feels ugly to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array containing as many json structures as you want.
It`d look something like this:

```
popover = this.editOptyPopup.create(EditOptyPage, [rw, json2, json3, json4], { cssClass: 'edit-opty-popover'});
```

Comment: how can we pass data to popover and retrieve it in popover component in ionic 4? this method returns undefined in ionic 4